# Moving photos into folders on iphone 5s

Tags: ios, photos, software-recommendation

How do I move photos from camera roll or My photo stream into other albums or folders in the iphone 5s? I'm using iOS 7.

Comment: What app do you want to use to organize photos into albums? iPhoto for iOS? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

in ios7:

- go to camera roll.
- in top right, choose 'select' select the photos
- you want to move by clicking them one after another.
- when done go to the bottom and click 'add to' then create a new album in bottom of
  list and they will be added.

Answer (score -1):

There's meanwhile the iOS app Utiful for moving photos into folders. Utiful is a complementary photo library, so you can freely move photos between the Camera Roll and the Utiful folders. So, unlike the Photos app than only duplicates photos into albums, Utiful makes it finally possible to physically MOVE photos out of the Camera Roll.
It's available both for iPhone and iPad, here's the link to the App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/utiful-divide-rule-your-photo/id1034958660?ls=1&mt=8